# Performance: Lots of Images vs Lots of Directories in a web server

Tags: php, linux, image, performance, server

So I am developing this website for a company and it may have, say approx 1,000-5,000 profiles (of vendors and users), so I have to store approx 10 images per vendor on a directory on the website's server (which will be retrieved using PHP), so I was wondering which will be a better performing way to do it. I have 2 choices:

1. Having all the images for all the profiles in a single folder (single folder having say 10,000 images)
2. Having separate directories for all the profiles having 10 images each (1,000 folders having 10 images each.)

So which way should the performance of website, on a server running linux, be better? I know that at this scale, it may not matter much to be a concern, but it may expand, have much more profiles than this and the server I am using is VERY slow (you can see the impact in performance after you include an extra PHP file).

I'll be using something like:

```
<?php
    for ($i = 1; file_exists("img/vendors/vendor_id_".$i.".jpg"); $i++)
    {
       echo "<img src=\"img/vendors/vendor_id_".$i.".jpg\">";
    }
 ?>
```

or

```
<?php
    for ($i = 1; file_exists("img/vendors/vendor_id/".$i.".jpg"); $i++)
    {
       echo "<img src=\"img/vendors/vendor_id/".$i.".jpg\">";
    }
?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to store them in separate folders, but I believe this is [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). I recommend putting them into a single folder for the sake of simplicity and if later you have performance issues, then you can migrate the folders. For now, handling all the folders would make it slower than the performance gain from separation.

Answer (score 0):

After looking many benchmarks (try google, there are many based on different scenarios), I found out that following is valid for most situations in a very crowded folder:

1. Adding new file/folder is usually slow
2. Deleting a file/folder is usually slow
3. Retrieving folder list is definitely slow
4. Accessing a specific file by name does not have much benchmark.

Actual results may change based on file system, hardware, file system parameters, etc, but the above list should give you a clue:

At least for maintenance, a wise man should follow a multi-folder structure.